# Can you force your ISP to delete IP address log?

Tags: ip

Good Evening,

Since the USA does not mandate data retention with law, and since one has a right to privacy, could you make your ISP delete IP address logs?

Comment: Yes. [EPFCG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explosively_pumped_flux_compression_generator)

Comment: No, in general, unless it's in your contract or against the law, you can't force your ISP to delete anything.

Comment: Right to what did you say? Therein lies a long and winding road that may not be what you think it is.